# Setting up a simple email forwarder on EC2

Tags: email, amazon-ec2, postfix, amazon-web-services

I'm migrating my personal website to be hosted on EC2. I've got the website part of it up and running, but I'm stuck getting the email server setup. All I'm trying to do is receive a small volume of emails (max 100/month) and forward them to my gmail address. I understand that [SES](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/Welcome.html) is the recommended email solution for AWS, but it is [not set up to act as a mail relay](https://sesblog.amazon.com/post/Tx3HQEJUJNVABG8/Receiving-Email-with-Amazon-SES) (ctrl + F "mail relay" to find a comment explaining this).

I set up postfix according to [these instructions](http://www.binarytides.com/postfix-mail-forwarding-debian/), and can verify that postfix is us and running on port 25 of my server:

```
# netstat -ltnp | grep 25
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:25                0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      15052/master
```

I've also verified that the MX DNS record is correctly pointing to the same DNS record my website uses (which I've verified is reachable):

```
# dig bleaney.ca mx

...

;; ANSWER SECTION:
bleaney.ca.             2975    IN      MX      0 bleaney.ca.
```

I've modified the security group applied to my EC2 instance to have the following rules:

```
80  tcp 0.0.0.0/0   ✔
22  tcp 0.0.0.0/0   ✔
25  tcp 0.0.0.0/0   ✔
```

Despite all this, when I send emails to my domain, nothing shows up in my postfix logs and no deliverable messages is returned to the mail provider I sent from. It appears as if something is still blocking port 25, because this is all I get back from a portscan:

```
Not shown: 996 filtered ports
PORT    STATE SERVICE
22/tcp  open  ssh
80/tcp  open  http
139/tcp open  netbios-ssn
445/tcp open  microsoft-ds
```

I have also filled out [this form](https://aws.amazon.com/forms/ec2-email-limit-rdns-request?catalog=true&isauthcode=true) and had email restrictions removed.

So, after all this, any idea what I've missed and how I can get this relay working?

Comment: Have you visit this thread http://serverfault.com/questions/610068/postfix-setup-on-aws-ec2-using-smtp-relay?

Comment: @ariestiyansyah, thanks for the link, however, I don't see anything in there that I haven't tried and is applicable to my issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why is postfix listening on the loopback interface?

In your netstat output, 127.0.0.1:25 should look like 0.0.0.0:25

```
nmap 52.32.135.192

Starting Nmap 6.47 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2016-01-03 04:33 EST
Nmap scan report for bleaney.ca (52.32.135.192)
Host is up (0.17s latency).
Not shown: 997 filtered ports
PORT   STATE  SERVICE
22/tcp open   ssh
25/tcp closed smtp
80/tcp open   http
```

Try setting:

```
inet_interfaces = all
```